# OpenGL FRONT_AND_BACK

Tags: android, opengl-es

I cull my objects using:

```
fx.g.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
fx.g.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
```

However when I set a blue material to my objects they show up as grey for:

```
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_BACK, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, ambient, 0);
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_BACK, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse, 0);
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_BACK, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, specular, 0);
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_BACK, GL10.GL_SHININESS, Ns, 0);
```

and

```
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, ambient, 0);
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse, 0);
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, specular, 0);
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT, GL10.GL_SHININESS, Ns, 0);
```

but blue for

```
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, ambient, 0);
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse, 0);
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, specular, 0);
fx.g.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_SHININESS, Ns, 0);
```

With the same values for ambient/diffuse/specular and ns.

Any ideas why this would be? it seems both GL_FRONT and GL_BACK materials are completely ignored, but GL_FRONT_AND_BACK works perfectly, not sure if they be a performance issue using this, or if it means I have bugs somewhere else!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems both `GL_FRONT` and `GL_BACK` materials are completely ignored

[Working as intended](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glMaterial.xml#parameters2):

> `face`: Specifies which face or faces are being updated. ***Must be `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK`***.

Comment: Well sounds about right, definitely seems to be what is happening, maybe I should make sure my tutorials match my opengl version! as http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMaterial.xml shows different. Ta for reply.

Comment: Well, yeah.  The documentation you linked to is for [OpenGL 2.x](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec21.20061201.pdf), not [OpenGL ES 1.x](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/1.1/es_full_spec_1.1.12.pdf).  Despite appearances they're (sometimes significantly!) different.